# Best puzzles of 2015 Q4 (October - December)?

Tags: discussion, best-of

*This question is part of the [best-puzzle award series](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of).*

---

> ### *What are your nominations for the best puzzles, here on Puzzling.SE, of the fourth quarter (Oct / Nov / Dec) 2015?*

Suggested guidelines for nomination:

- Nominate each individual puzzle in a separate answer, so they can be upvoted/downvoted separately.
- No more than 3 nominations per person.
- Don't nominate your own puzzles.
- Before you nominate a puzzle, check to see if someone else has already nominated it. If they have then add to that nomination as a comment (or edit it), instead of nominating the same puzzle again.
- **In your nomination, explain what it is that (in your opinion) makes the nominated puzzle such a good one.**

---

> Some lists to help jog your memory (your nomination doesn't have to be from these lists):
>
> - [Questions with the most ***votes*** from 2015 Q4](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106579?StartDate=2015/10/01#query-results)
> - [Questions with the most ***views*** from 2015 Q4](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106705?StartDate=2015/10/01#query-results)
> - [Questions with the highest-voted ***answers*** from 2015 Q4](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106709?StartDate=2015/10/01#query-results)

---

Meta-meta issues:

- Is this kind of thing allowed on SE?

  - Yes, [photo.SE](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest) and [scifi.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3142/favorite-questions-and-answers-from-third-quarter-of-2013?rq=1) do something very similar.
- What's the point?

  - To highlight and encourage good practice in a way that goes beyond upvotes.
  - To work towards building a 'hall of fame' of some of the best puzzles on the site (perhaps to reside on a future puzzling.SE blog) - think of it as our 'greatest hits album'. :)
  - To prompt members to put forward their own reflections on what makes a high-quality puzzle.

Comment: I love how there are 5 upvotes, but no nominations...

Comment: I'd love to see a summary of good puzzles, but don't have the time to look them up ;-)

Answer (score 4):

### [Three voting prisoners](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22784/three-voting-prisoners)

*by [Tyler Seacrest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2722)*

This puzzle is basically a variation of the 100 prisoner problem, yet gathered a lot of views and responses from users determined to figure out the steak vs. fish taco dilemma.  It also helps that the answer from matega was elegantly simple and unintended, yet perfect.

Answer (score 3):

### [Emojiture Challenge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24124/emojiture-challenge)

*by [Sleafar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/15632)*

Not a hard puzzle, but one of the most beautiful and elegant ones I've seen on here.  Very simple rules, well presented, with a clean and unambiguous solution.  The goal of a good puzzle is to be enjoyable to solve, and that one nails it.